# C++ program terminate when entering more than 11 integer

Tags: c++

I have a program written in C++ that ask a user to enter his/her 11 digit
 mobile number. But when I enter the 11 digits, the program `continue` without
 executing the succeding code.

```
 string FriendName, FriendAdd,  EmailAdd;
 long MobileNumber, counter, counter1, counter2;
 //Create a new structure
 struct personData {
   string namePerson, addressPerson, emailAddress;
   long age;
   struct personData *next;
 };

//Initialize pointers to personData structure
typedef struct personData node;

node *firstRec, *currentRec, *tempRec, *tempRec2;

void InsertRec() {
  cin.ignore(200,'\n');

  cout<<"Enter your Friend's Name            : ";
  cin.ignore(1,'\n');
  getline(cin,FriendName);
  cout<<"Enter your Friend's Mobile Number   : ";
  cin>>MobileNumber;
  cout<<"Enter your Friend's Address         : ";
  cin.ignore(1,'\n');
  getline(cin,FriendAdd);
  cout<<"Enter your Friend's Email Add       : ";
  getline(cin,EmailAdd);
  cout<<endl<<endl;

  tempRec = new(personData);
  tempRec->namePerson = FriendName;
  tempRec->addressPerson = FriendAdd;
  tempRec->emailAddress = EmailAdd;
  tempRec->age = MobileNumber;
  tempRec->next=firstRec;
  //firstRec->next=tempRec;

  firstRec=tempRec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  Was there a question?

Comment: I guess because you forget the cin.ignore you used so widely. I would recommend using cin.getline() instead for user inpput - and please: store the number not into a long variable but String instead

Comment: Phone numbers should be strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of integral types depends on target platform and compiler settings. Assuming that `long` is a 32-bit integer, it only supports 10 digits.

The maximum values for 32-bit integral types are:

signed: -2147483647 to 2147483647
unsigned: 0 to 4294967295

A better approach would be to store the mobile number as a string, not a number.

Comment: This is only true for a *32 bit* `long`.

Comment: @PaulR long is (usually) 32bit on x86

Comment: @JustMaximumPower: And it's often 64-bit on x64. But that's irrelevant to the question - phone numbers are strings of (usually) digits, not integers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour my point was that I agree with you, and Mark was justified in assuming a 32 bit long.

Comment: @JustMaximumPower: nowhere in the OP's question or tags does it mention x86 or anything platform-specific which might allow you to infer a 32 bit architecture.

Comment: @PaulR actually the fact that it doesn't work with 11 digit numbers tells me that long is 32 bit. However this entire discussion is pointless, like Mike already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

A phone number is not an integer, it is a string of numbers.

The maximum number a signed integer (for 32-bit integer, which is used depends on your platform and compiler)   can contain is +2,147,483,647. Which is 10 digits.

Comment: This is only true for a *32 bit* integer.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem of datatype you have chosen to take mobile number. After entering mobile number, print it again and see whether it shows same value or not.
Your 11 digit value exceeds `long` limit.